# System.debug message only shows in logs when outside of classes or methods in VScode

Tags: apex, class, vs-code, method

I'm trying to see the system.debug message in the output console log when I run the SFDX: Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor Contents, but it doesn't seem to want to appear. I've seen a lot of different articles about setting up an active trace flag and moving VScode into applications (I'm on a Mac) and out of downloads. However, can't seem to get it to work.

Alternatively, when I run the execute anonymous code command when the system.debug is on it own it works. Not sure where to go next.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a class doesn't cause the code contained in it (in constructors or methods) to be executed.

To execute the code in your constructor, you'll need to actually construct an instance of your class.

i.e. you need to add

```java
Class_Test testInstance = new Class_Test();
```

after your class definition